# Не выполнять код при каком-то условии

Tags: любой-язык, логика

Нужно чтоб при определенном условии, код переставал работать.
Если точнее то к примеру

```
if (count == 0)
{
  код
}
```

и вот если count действительно равно нулю, код не должен выполнятся.

Comment: Чудесно. Объясните, какая разница между просто "равен нулю" и "действительно равен нулю".

Comment: @Igor игра слов, чтоб не было вечной тавтологии

Comment: Тавтология - это когда вы прежде уже использовали конструкцию ранее. Вы же ее еще не использовали. И вообще - главное понятность. Если точно не уверены, что вы не теряете в смысловой нагрузке(или, что не создаете неправильную), то лучше повториться, чем потенциально запутать читающих

Comment: @Miron я про тавтологию в плане слова "просто равен" и действительно равен", я просто не стал писать два раза одно и тоже слово, это вполне можно счесть за тавтологию

Comment: @PSENHI Как ни искал, не нашел ни одного употребления слов "просто" и "равен" до этого в тексте(думаю, что вы не про код). Но это пустое. Если вас ответ удовлетворил - принимайте. Иначе спрашивайте непонятные вещи в комментариях

Comment: @Miron по сути вы можете быть правы , может просто я сейчас не до конца понял что написал и сижу еще спорю.
Насчет кода - я решил оставить до завтра и пока не пробовал ничего, ибо весь день потратил на то чтоб разобраться в нем, не в этих строчках, а в плане сидел и перебирал

Comment: @Miron сейчас я думаю только над приветствием для телеграм бота, но до меня уже второй день не доходит в чем проблема, и просто не понимаю что не так пишу

Comment: @PSENHI Советую изучить сперва основы: https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/2.11.php . Время - дорогой ресурс, и тратить его на выстрелы в колено недопустимо. Лучше разберитесь с устройством пистолета для начала.

Comment: @Miron к сожалению муторное чтение мануалов, на мою полупустую головушку не влияет, только практика, только "хардкор"...

Comment: @PSENHI Поверьте, это может быть увлекательно. Просто примите к сведению, что для начала нужно ПОНЯТЬ то, чем вы будете пользоваться, только потом можно будет это использовать. В противном случае вы наошибаетесь, ничего не поймете и выгорите. Весь кайф, когда ты пишешь код и понимаешь, что ты делаешь. Тупое написание кода лично меня демотивирует. Не люблю пользоваться тем, об устройстве чего я не знаю хотя бы в общих чертах.

Comment: @Miron да, это так, но еще я ловлю кайф когда бьюсь над кодом, он не работает, но по итогу все начинает работать так как я хотел.
Насчет "тупого написания" , меня не демотивирует лично, я просто устаю от того что куча проб и ошибок, а результат в крупицах

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменять условие на противоположное:

```
if (count != 0)
```

Ну или в более общем случае:

```
if (!(count == 0))
```

Comment: Ещё вариант — добавить ветку else

Comment: @АндрейNOP Это в случае, если нужно выполнить что-то, когда условие неверно(иначе не выполнять).

Comment: @АндрейNOP, можно, но если основная часть пустая, то это какое-то извращение...